# Filter large CSV file

Tags: python, csv, filter

In python I have created this small code to filter a CSV file based on another CSV file. With small sample files it works, but I have a CSV file with 43 mio. rows (2.8 GB file), and then this does not work.

FileA contains the list of things i need, and fileB need to be filtered based on FileA (First 4 columns in both files contain same columns). Any suggestion to another method to do this?

```
from csv import reader
from csv import writer

 with open('C:\\temp\\mat_filter_large.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fileA, \
 open('C:\\temp\\bom_large.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fileB, \
 open('C:\\temp\\out_large.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as outB:

csv_writer = writer(outB,delimiter=';')

readerA = reader(fileA,delimiter=';')
readerB = reader(fileB,delimiter=';')

A_map = {(col1, col2, col3, col4) for col1, col2, col3, col4, *_ in readerA}

for col1, col2, col3, col4, *rest in readerB:

    if (col1, col2, col3, col4) in A_map:
        csv_writer.writerow([col1, col2, col3, col4, *rest])
```

Comment: It doesn't work meaning? Whats the error?

Comment: The large file is A or B?

Comment: I did run the code from VScode, and it crashed, from consol it works, but slow.

fileB (2.8 gb and 44 mio rows) fileA  (150mb  and 3 mio rows)